# C implementation of merge sort, as shown in Cormen's et al "Introduction to algortithms" not working properly

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to implement, using C, this Merge Sort pseudocode[image]

And I've come up with this

```
int p = 0, r = SEIZE-1, i, j, k;
int q = (p + r)/2;
int n1 = q-p+1, n2 = r-q;
float A[SEIZE] = { 125.6, 67.2, 3.21, 422, 54, 87 }, L[n1], R[n2];

printf("{ ");
for( k = 0 ; k < SEIZE ; k++ ){
    printf("%.1f ", A[k]);
}
printf(" }\n");

for( i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++ ){
    L[i] = A[p+i];
}
for( j = 0 ; j < n2 ; j++ ){
    R[j] = A[q+j+1];
}
L[n1] = '\0';
R[n2] = '\0';

i = 0;
j = 0;

for( k = p ; k <= r; k++ ){
    if( L[i] <= R[j] ){
        A[k] = L[i];
        i = i+1;
    }
    else{
        A[k] = R[j];
        j = j+1;
    }
}

printf("{ ");
for( k = 0 ; k < SEIZE ; k++ ){
    printf("%.1f ", A[k]);
}
printf(" }\n");
```

However, this happens [image]

The first set of numbers is the unsorted one, the second is supossed to be 
the sorted one, but as you can see, the algorithm is not sorting it; I think the problem stems from wrongly trying to convert base-1 arrays from the book, to C's base-0, but I'm not really sure. Can you help me spotting the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the full code?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code, but by far the biggest is that you think your algorithm is supposed to sort the array. It is not.

The "merge" function is just one part of merge-sort; its function is to take two already-sorted subarrays — *A*[*p*..*q*−1] and *A*[*q*..*r*], I think, if I'm interpreting your pseudocode rightly — and merge them into a single already-sorted subarray — *A*[*p*..*r*].

So to test your implementation of that function, you need to give it an array whose two parts are already sorted.

And to get a fully sorted array, you need to finish your implementation of merge-sort. (Your book presumably either gives you the rest of the algorithm on a page you haven't read yet, or sets it as an exercise.)

Comment: Yes .true. I don't know how OP is so sure that this is where the problem lies...anyway this breaks `MCVE` ( I mean the question). I will UV as it is right.

Answer (score 1):

- You are mixing up 1-indexing and 0-indexing. You should follow what the algorithm says (1-indexing) or simply you can write your own version of 0-indexing.
- Also looking at the magnitude of the error. I think, you are not passing two sorted arrays to the merge function. If you consider carefully, `merge` is nothing but the putting the sorted arrays in order together. I guess you should check whether that arrays are sorted or not.
- Infinity shouldn't be replaced with `\0`. That's not logical. You can do it by using `INT_MAX` or something similar.
- Check the part of the programs first. First check whether the sort functions are working. If it works then go for merge. That way you will easily find where your problem is.

Example code:

```
int merge(int *arr, int left, int middle, int right)
{
  int len1 = middle - left + 1;
  int len2 = right - middle;

  int arr1[len1];
  int arr2[len2];

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<len1; ++i)
    arr1[i] = arr[left + i];

  for (i=0; i<len2; ++i)
    arr2[i] = arr[middle + 1 + i];

  arr1[len1] = INT_MAX;
  arr2[len2] = INT_MAX;

  int j,k;
  j = 0;
  i = 0;

  for (k=left; k<=right; ++k)
    arr[k] = (arr1[i] <= arr2[j])? arr1[i++]:arr2[j++];

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont put `L[n1]='\0'` and `R[n2]='\0'`
Instead use this logic for merging

```
i=0
j=0
k=p
while(i<n1&&j<n2)
{
    if(L[i]<=R[j])
    {
        arr[k]=L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k]=R[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
//This following code for copying      remaining elements
while(i<n1)
{
    arr[k]=L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
while(j<n2)
{
    arr[k]=R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
```